# When starting an android project i got this : "ERROR: Module 'app': platform 'android-27' not found."

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, sdk

So i just started an Android Kotlin project in IntelliJ IDEA Community edition and the first build doesn't work at all. Just throw me that : `ERROR: Module 'app': platform 'android-27' not found.`

[This is my SDK and Android downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW8hd.png)

This is my 'app' build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "...."
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

---

**EDIT** : 
Tried in Android Studio and it actually works with no error. So that's basically an error in my configuration of IntelliJ IDEA .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This clearly means that the SDK platforms haven't been installed.
Click on the SDK Tools tab in the SDK Manger and install all the required Android SDKs.
If you have already installed, then update them.

Comment: I did update them, still nothing. So i'm just gonna switch on Android Studio. This is blowing me haha. Thanks for the help